# Devise: Logout *without* redirecting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise, render, logout

Im trying to logout with devise but without redirecting! So I want to disable the redirect after logout. The reason for this is I want to render a certain template instead.
***How to logout a user from devise without redirecting them for --> this method only <--?*** Im already overriding the devise session controller.

My method ( called from before filter in application_controller.rb)

```
  def check_concurrent_session
    if user_signed_in?
      if current_user && !(session[:token] == current_user.login_token)
        render :template => "users/logout_duplex", :layout => "application", :locals => { sub_layout => "left" }
        # The next line always redirects to signout_path
        # I want to disable the complete redirect so it just logs out and shows the rendered template
        Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(@user)
        return
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Inherit sessions controller from devise and have your own implementation of `after_sign_out_path_for`. That's the method devise uses to redirect after signout.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

 protected
 def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  //your implementation
 end
end
```

Add this to your config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions'}
```

Devise implementation of the method looks like below

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
 respond_to?(:root_path) ? root_path : "/"
end
```

Comment: I know I can override the devise controllers and already did that but this is not a answer to the question. I want to only make the redirect disabled for this method i posted not app-wide ( edit question to make that more clear )

Comment: What do you mean this method? you mean that action? after_sign_out_path_for is the method where you can do that.

Comment: yes but is is application wide, i want to only -1time- sign out without redirecting, the existing redirect location that is set by the method you suggest, i want to keep intact

Comment: Just calling the method sign_out doesn't redirect to the root_path. I think i am missing something. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb. The destroy method in that link calls signout and then redirects to the after_sign_out_path.

Comment: Using the line from my example. Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(@user) *does* use the def after_sign_out_path location to redirect, which i -not- want to happen and thats why this question